# Invalid Parameter number not allowed issue in PDO MySql When using Group By

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, group-by, date-format

I am having an issue with grouping dates together in MySQL.

Here is my whole code on calling from the database:

```
// Make todays date
$todays_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now')) . '00:00:00';

// Get all from database and group them by day
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT bookingdate FROM madebookings WHERE bookingdate >= :$todays_date GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(bookingdate,'%b, %d %Y')");
$query->execute(array(':todays_date' => $todays_date));
$query_number = $query->rowCount();

// Lets build the table
$files_table = '';

if ($query_number > 0) {
    while ($fetch = $query->fetch()) {
        //get the items needed
        $bookingdate = $sanitise->justDate(date('Y-m-d', $fetch['bookingdate']));
        $dateUrl     = $date('Y-m-d', $fetch['bookingdate']);

        $files_table .="<tr>";          
        $files_table .= "<td>".$bookingdate."</td>";
        $files_table .= "<td><a href='view-day-bookings.php?date=".$dateUrl."' class=\"btn btn-info btn-sm btn-icon icon-left\"><i class=\"entypo-pencil\"></i>Click here to view bookings</a></td>";
        $files_table .= "</tr>";
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /XXX/XXX/Documents/www/Applications/Controllers/Bookings/group.php on line 8

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in /XXX/XXX/Documents/www/Applications/Controllers/Bookings/group.php on line 8
```

As you can see the issue is on the execute line which I suspect that its thinking it needs to put the %b, %d %Y into a prepared statement, I may be wrong on this though :(

Anyway can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: :todays_date and not :$todays_date source : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

I used a $ instead of : in this statement section:

```
WHERE bookingdate >= :$todays_date
```

Issue is now fixed :)